# libGDXで例外が出る

Tags: java

eclipseでlibGDXを使おうと考えていますが、デフォルトであるクラス(badlogicの画像表示)を実行しても、以下のような例外が出てしまいました。

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException        
>   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.createDisplayPixelFormat
>   (LwjglGraphics.java:321)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGraphics.setupDisplay(LwjglGraphics.java:215)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:142)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)

一番上のLwjglGraphics.java:321では
`throw new GdxRuntimeException("OpenGL is not supported by the video driver: " + glVersion.getDebugVersionString(), ex3);`
とあり、OpenGL関係だろうとは思いますが、原因が分かりません。
分かる人がいましたら、教えていただけるとうれしいです。
OS はwindows10 64bit,　eclipseは4.6.0,Gradleはプラグイン済みです。

Comment: グラフィックカードのドライバは最新ですか？

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38806017/libgdx-nullpointerexception-for-the-default-code

こちらに同様の質問と回答があります。
ざっくり訳しますと、

ゲーム起動コードに以下の行を追加してください。

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

起動コードは以下のようになると思われます。

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LwjglApplicationConfiguration config = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
      System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
      config.title = "Mygame"; 
      config.width = 1920;
      config.height = 1080;
      new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), config);
   }
}
```

また、グラフィックドライバを更新してください。

Comment: 元の回答のコメントにあるように、ソフト実装を許可してもエラーが変わるだけで多分動かないと思います

Comment: 同意です。グラフィックドライバの更新が必要と思われます。http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28867285/lwjgl-reports-that-opengl-is-not-supported-on-a-modern-nvidia-card こちらの質問が参考になります。加えて、いずれにせよglVersionが初期化されなければいけないので、ソフト実装も必要と思われます。